# how do i install Vue.js using cli on my local machine using Apache?

Tags: apache, installation, command-line-interface, vue.js, command-prompt

I installed node.js, run apache via xampp, and configured my apache server so that I can use [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as my practice server domain on my local machine.

I started my command prompt as admin and typed the following lines but and they all ran successfully:

## install vue-cli

```
$ npm install --global vue-cli
```

## create a new project using the "webpack" template

```
$ vue init webpack my-project
```

## install dependencies and go!

```
$ cd my-project
$ npm install
$ npm run dev
```

I followed the cli installation section on https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html

When I go to my folders, all the vue.js files are installed inside 'my-project', but when I go to my apache server at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or [www.example.com/my-project](http://www.example.com/my-project), a blank page shows. And if I got into my index.html file in the 'my-project' folder and edit it to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>project3</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">sdfsf</div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I just get a blank page with the text sdfsf. What am I doing wrong? why isn't vue.js hello install screen page loading?

Comment: after `npm run dev`, if you just go to browser and enter `http://localhost:8080/`, what do you see?

Comment: wow, it is installed there, I missed it, thanks, lol, my bad :)

Comment: how do I change which port it is installed on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run:

```
npm run dev
```

It starts a Node JS server. The exact command can be found in `package.json`, and you can see the result by going to `http://localhost:8080/`.

Comment: how do I change the port number it's run on if I want a different port than 8080? I can't find anything in package.json regarding port number.

Comment: @SimonSuh It will in the config folder, port should be mentioned in the file which is being used when you  run `npm run dev`(see `package.json` for this). In my case it is `config/index.js`